# Paypal issue with paypal_base.dll

Tags: .net, paypal, upgrade, tls1.2

I have updated my project from `.net framework` 3.5 to 4.5, I have been using Paypal Signature Authentication method which uses `paypal_base.dll`. Due to [Paypal update](https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/tls-http-upgrade) regarding TLS sandbox stop working and I need to fix it. I have made following changes;

added section for paypal in web.config inside configSection

```
<section name="paypal" type="com.paypal.sdk.core.ConfigSectionHandler, paypal_base" />
```

in configuration

```
<paypal>
    <endpoints>
      <wsdl>
        <environment name="live">
          <port name="PayPalAPI">https://api.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
          <port name="PayPalAPIAA">https://api-aa.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
          <port name="PayPalAPI" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
          <port name="PayPalAPIAA" threetoken="true">https://api-aa-3t.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
        </environment>
        <environment name="sandbox">
          <port name="PayPalAPI">https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
          <port name="PayPalAPIAA">https://api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
          <port name="PayPalAPI" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
          <port name="PayPalAPIAA" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/</port>
        </environment>
      </wsdl>
    </endpoints>
  </paypal>
```

still I am facing same issue `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` If I do it with fidller to bypass TLS i get the error of Bad Request.